# How to browse by album art in rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, plugins

**How do I browse album covers in Rhythmbox?**

I'm looking for how to browse album art in newer versions of Rhythmbox

I tried [Rhythmarty](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rhythmarty/) plug in but I think it's very old so it can't be used, it does not appear on the plug in list.

Other options require gnome 2 and I use Gnome-Shell.

Answer (score 12):

### 12.04 and later

Browse your coverart albums in Rhythmbox v2.96 and later

[image: Imgur]

*first the disclaimer* - I am the co-author to this plugin!

[How it works](https://github.com/fossfreedom/coverart-browser/wiki/How-the-plugin-works):

- Click the new CoverArt source button (left hand side of screen)
- Albums are displayed as clickable buttons containing their album cover
- Right click menu option to play, queue & search for cover art for an album.

[image: Imgur]

- to search for missing covers

[image: Imgur]

- locale support is also available to display text in your native language - more details on how to help with the translation is on [GitHub](https://github.com/fossfreedom/coverart-browser).

For full instructions see the projects Wiki:

- https://github.com/fossfreedom/coverart-browser/wiki/How-the-plugin-works

For instructions on how to download great coverart:

- https://github.com/fossfreedom/coverart-browser/wiki/How-to-find-great-coverart

**how to install**

The installation instructions cover the installation of each individual plugin.  If you prefer a PPA method skip to the bottom:

for rhythmbox 2.96 to 2.99.1:

```
sudo apt-get install git gettext python-mako python-lxml
```

for rhythmbox 3.0 or compiled from git:

```
sudo apt-get install git gettext python3-mako python3-lxml
```

Then install the coverart browser plugin for rhythmbox version 2.96 to 2.99.1:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins/coverart_browser
git clone https://github.com/fossfreedom/coverart-browser.git
cd coverart-browser
./install.sh
```

To install the coverart browser plugin for rhythmbox version 3.0 and later:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins/coverart_browser
git clone https://github.com/fossfreedom/coverart-browser.git
cd coverart-browser
./install.sh --rb3
```

To install the coverart search-providers plugin for rhythmbox 2.96 - 2.99:

```
sudo apt-get install git gettext python-mako python-mutagen python-requests
```

for rhythmbox 3.0 or compiled from git:

```
sudo apt-get install git gettext python3-mako python3-requests
```

Then install the coverart search-providers plugin:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins/coverart_search_providers
git clone https://github.com/fossfreedom/coverart-search-providers.git
cd coverart-search-providers
```

For rhythmbox 2.96 to 2.99:

```
./install.sh
```

For rhythmbox 3.0 or compiled from git:

```
./install.sh --rb3
```

Alternative installation - I've added this to my Rhythmbox PPA:

- [How do I install third-party rhythmbox plugins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be compatible with the latest version

Comment: Doesn't work for me neither... (Ubuntu 17.04 GNOME 3.24)

Answer (score 1):

### 11.04 and previous

I found another one [rhythmbox-cover-art-browser](http://code.google.com/p/rhythmbox-cover-art-browser/)

> The plugin enables to display a cover grid view in the middle pane of
>   rhythmbox a button enables to fetch missing covers double clicking on
>   a cover plays the album drag and drop of album art supported

#### Download:

[here](http://code.google.com/p/rhythmbox-cover-art-browser/downloads/list). Give it a try though I don't use Rhythmbox So I couldn't test it.

#### Preview:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### 10.10

I do not have the current version of Rhythmbox, but in my older version I got it to work.  Confirm that you:

1. Put the artdisplay_browser folder (extracted from the download) in the `/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins` folder.  Note you may have to be root to add it, I also set permissions to 755 for the files and folder.
2. In Rhythmbox open the plugins menu and select the `artdisplay_browser` plugin to activate.

And it works very nice for me!

Comment: You may want to provide information about how to set the permissions (either in Nautilus, with `chmod`, or both). Many user reading this may not be familiar with how to do that.