# How could Rhythmbox deal with multiple-disc albums

Tags: rhythmbox, music

Title pretty much says it all. My Rhythmbox confuses the first disc of the Les Miserables soundtrack [deluxe edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A80SHFM) with the second disc, the effect being that the song titles are all wrong.

Look at this screenshot:

[image: Rhythmbox wrong album info]

It shows 19 tracks, which is the number of tracks in disc two, but track info from disc one. Even the time field is all wrong; when I took this screenshot, *Javert's Suicide* was still playing though Rhythmbox says that the play time for track 11 is over.

Comment: Do they both have the same Album title? Just import them one at a time, creating new play lists with each album to separate them. Or edit the song info by right-clicking and selecting 'Properties'

Comment: Isnt this the same as this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/232427/how-can-i-get-rhythmbox-to-see-that-different-albums-with-the-same-name-are-diff

Comment: @wilf Yes unfortunately. I've tried manually adding the disc number in the given field hoping for some magic but nada.

Comment: @fossfreedom, I've seen that but I think this is different in that my case is actually _same_ album but different disc numbers (disc 1 vs disc 2).

Comment: hmm - the only "disc 1 and disc 2" albums I have got actually have the disc number in the album name.  Are you happy to-do this with your tracks?  If so I can throw an answer showing you how to rename stuff in bulk.

Comment: @fossfreedom, that would be much appreciated though I'll hang out a bit to see if better suggestions come along.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many tagging software such as EasyTag, Picard use a variety of techniques help media players such as Rhythmbox that don't deal with Multi-disc albums very well.

Commonly they append the disc number to the album title in the format `(disc x`) where `x` is the disc number.

I've grouped some of these in my collection as shown in the following picture.

[image]

Now - the easiest way to do this is using Rhythmbox itself if its one of the common file types such as MP3, OGG.  If you are using something Rhythmbox doesnt allow you to modify (see later) then its best to use software such as EasyTag and Picard to modify the tags in the music files themselves.  Then Rhythmbox will see the modified album titles.

One technique I use is to add the file location to the tracks window - use the Preferences option to do this.  Then you can order by file-location to group all the tracks in one file-location.  Typically you would copy all tracks for album-disc 1 in the same location - album-disc2 will be is a separate folder.

Highlight all the tracks for one album, right-click and select properties

[image]

Finally, append the disc number to the album-title as shown and click OK.

[image]

All the album tags for the multiple tracks chosen will be updated.

Comment: After two days, manual seems to be the best way to deal with my problems (for now). Also, I did not know that you can edit MP3 metadata in Rhythmbox. That seems to make EasyTAG redundant. Or not? Why should I keep it installed?

Comment: Rhythmbox only allows you to edit a few audio types such as mp3.  EasyTag allows you to edit a much wider variety of types such as FLAC that rhythmbox will not allow you to write to.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the album title of the Deluxe edition from `Les Miserables: Something` to `Les Miserables: Something (Deluxe)`, Rhythmbox will separate it out...

Disc numbers don't seem make much difference, because it does not order the files with them, they are just there for extra info. When rhythmbox displays the list of music, you can order the list view by what it shown *(Title, Genre, Artist, Album, etc - you can set this in Rhythmbox's Preferences)* by clicking on 'Title' etc at the top of the list (only in the main Music playlist though).

This can means for example when you order by Album (or Artist, Genre, etc), the 'Greatest Hits' and 'Best Of' albums all get mixed up. So the easiest solution is to rename.

You could [File a Bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=rhythmbox) if you want (there may be one already), as this always has been a long standing problem, though there is not much that could be done about it easily.