# Rhythmbox jumps to selected album

Tags: rhythmbox

When Rhythmbox finishes playing a song, it jumps to play the next song of the selected album. This is all well and good BUT the selected album may be different than the currently playing album, and I may not wish to play it - I may be merely browsing my library.

I realize this is probably 'works as designed' and not a bug - but it is really annoying and makes browsing the music library practically impossible for more than a length of a given song. I must browse back to the current album before the song finishes, or else it goes to play whatever is selected.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

The observation is a *feature* of rhythmbox - it has always been done this way.

So - "Is there any way around this?"

Yes & No.

- **First the No.**

There is no method directly from the library browser - this is (as its name suggests) - built for searching and navigating your music library.

- **Yes**

From the library browser you can create playlists - you can highlight all the tracks from an album - right click and create a playlist of your album.

Thus you can play from the playlist and when the album finishes, no more tracks are played.

Yes - this sounds like a workaround - that's how the default rhythmbox works.

- **better way**

First the disclaimer - I'm the author of the following.

Rhythmbox handling of albums is rather lacklustre - which is why I created the coverart-browser plugin.

[image: Imgur]

By playing from the plugin:

1. Double clicking the album, or
2. pressing the space-bar when an album icon is highlighted, or
3. right clicking and choosing play-album

Rhythmbox will then play all the tracks for the album - and more importantly finish playing at the end of the album/albums that were initially selected.

---

Linked Question:

- [How to browse by album art in rhythmbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112148/how-to-browse-by-album-art-in-rhythmbox/145282#145282)